# decompose() function error

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to execute "Holt Winters" forecasting algorithm in R on a file which contains two columns, viz., 'Dates' and 'Values'.
This file captures the number of occurrences for an event ('Values' column) for a particular date.

[You can download and view the file as a Google doc.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0sOaP5YUqkyLVcyWkU0empXRnM)

Let the data be referred to as 'D', then

```
head(D)

Dates         Values
2013-11-13    805
2013-11-14    609
2013-11-15    661
2013-11-16    330
2013-11-17    344
2013-11-18    884
```

I convert the 'Dates' column to contain date data type with-

```
D$Dates <- as.Date(D$Dates, "%d-%m-%y")
```

The numerical values in 'Values' column are random and the range of dates in 'Dates' column start from 13-Nov-2013 till 31-Aug-2014.

I then make a time series object out of it for day wise observations using-

```
D_ts <- ts(D$Values, start = c(2013, 11), end = c(2014, 8), frequency = 365)
```

Note- According to my understanding, the 'frequency' argument is the number of observations per cycle and I want it to be every day of the month hence I have taken the value of 365. Correct me if I am wrong.

Upon trying to use 'decompose()' function on the 'D_ts' variable, I get the following error-

```
decompose(D_ts)
```

> Error in decompose(D_ts) : time series has no or less than 2 periods

I am not able to figure out the reason for this error. Any ideas?

Comment: You set the `frequency` too high. You have 9 months of data (approx 275 days), but are trying to decompose the data into a cycle with 365 days. You need at least two years of data to decompose any yearly seasonality. You can find weakly seasonality by setting `frequency = 7`. More information on [frequency](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/) and have a look at [related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=time+series+has+no+or+less+than+2+periods).

Comment: I have tried with **frequency = 275** and also with **frequency = 304** since it's from Nov-2013 to Aug-2014 [30, 31, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31] which sum up to 304. But it still gives the same error when using 'decompose()' function _Error in decompose(D_ts) : time series has no or less than 2 periods_

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific to declare ts

D_ts <- ts(D[a:b,2], start = c(2013, 11), end = c(2014, 8), frequency = 365)

a and b are the range of your data and 2 because is the second column

Comment: Rodrigo, the code that you have written wouldn't work. The version of it that would work is- `D_ts <- ts(D[1:292, 2], start = c(2013, 11), end = c(2014, 8), frequency = 365)`. Because **D$VALUES** refers to the second column. Also, doing so gives me the same error as before when using "decompose() i.e., _Error in decompose(D_ts) : time series has no or less than 2 periods_ Thanks for your input! Any other suggestions